# Android weird display behaviour with soft keyboard

Tags: android

I click a button and launch an activity with a soft keyboard:

[image]

When I click on the Cancel button, it calls finish() to exit to the first page. Then when I launch the activity again i get this:

[image]

The layout with the buttons is now hidden behind the keyboard.

In another scenario if i do it this way:

1. Launch activity.
2. Click back button to dismiss keyboard.
3. Click back button to go to first page.
4. Launch activity.

I get picture 1. The buttons don't get hidden. Seems like I have to destroy the keyboard before calling finish().

How do I solve this problem?

Edit: Added example of what's in the Manifest

```
 <activity            
        android:name=".SignUp"
        android:theme="@style/DefaultTitle" />
```

This is in my manifest as well, I added it after reading some other posts, didn't work for me.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="7" />
```

Ok LOL. Weird discovery. If I do this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(cancel.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception e) {                 
            }
            finish();
```

it works! Not sure if this is a good workaround....

Comment: It seems you must give the keyboard enough time to dismiss before you kill the activity or the state still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in your activity tag and let me know what happen,

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" . . . >
```

For more info look at [android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Comment: This launches the activity with the keyboard closed I want it to be visible when it first launches.

Comment: I think when you clicked on your edittext then it will open the keyboard.

Comment: Yes, which is not what I want, I want to open the keyboard when I launch the activity and not trigger it by clicking on the edittext.

Comment: And what about these two properties "stateAlwaysVisible" and "stateVisible" have you tried it?

Comment: I posted all I needed to post. There is no code, everything is on default.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are showing the SoftKeyBoard Using `STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE` Thats Why it remain visible when you comes back to the activity.

So Try to open keyboard on Button Click this way..

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEdit);
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
// only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

And if there are any `windowSoftInputMode` in Manifest,Remove them cause will not need them for above method.

Comment: You were right with the STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE, I removed it and tried your code, but still same result.

Comment: where you are enabeling the soft keyboard..check isn't it like ..that portion of code is getting called everytime you resume that activity..or post the whole code here so all can see and help you better

Comment: There is no code when the keyboard shows. It auto sets focus on the edittext then the keyboard appears. It's on default mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try using setfocus method on object of edittext